# Grafana variable - Interval mutiplier

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I am drawing a graph in grafana where I am getting the rate of one counter and subtracting it from rate of another counter.
I am using the Interval Variable in the graph.
Now when I want to use 5m as interval, I want the rate to be multiplied (5*60).
Similarly when 1h then it should be multiplied by  (1 * 24 * 60 * 60)

> `$period  = 1m,5m,10m,1h and like this.`

My query

```
rate(service_total{state="otp_send"}[$period]) * 300 - ignoring(state) rate(service_total{state="otp_validate"}[$period]) *300
```

So I want this 300 to be put in a variable which changes when I change the $period value in grafana

```
> If $period is 5m, 300 should be 300 
> If $period is 1m, 300 should be 60
> If $period is 10m, 300 should be 600
```

And in this way.
Is there something that I can do in grafana.

SO basically I want to attach the $period to a constant variable that multiplies according to the interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  increase(service_total{state="otp_send"}[$period]) 
- ignoring(state) 
  increase(service_total{state="otp_validate"}[$period])
```

`increase` is syntactic sugar on top of `rate` that does this.

Answer (score 1):

You can change from "rate(vector)*time" to "delta(vector)" to get the same result, like the following:

```
delta(service_total{state="otp_send"}[$period]) - ignoring(state) delta(service_total{state="otp_validate"}[$period])
```

More info in the Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta).

UPDATE:

As @brian-brazil replied, the correct in this case is to use the "increase" function instead of the "delta" function because the second one doesn't deal with counter resets.

More info in the Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase)

Comment: It is incorrect to use `delta` with counters, and in general it is not a function to use as you usually want either `deriv` or `increase` instead.

Comment: I can't see the difference between "delta" and "increase" when used with counters. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: Delta doesn't deal with counter resets, as it's intended for gauges.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you think is it better to remove the answer to not confuse people?

Comment: That's up to you, maybe an edit to indicate why it's incorrect? It's not an uncommon mistake.

Comment: I think this answer is more useful because a) it links to documentation and b) it explains why it is wrong :)